# Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, laravel

```html
<td> {{ $item->salary }} </td>
@if($item['advance']['advance_salary'] == NULL )
    <p>No Advance</p>
@else
    {{ $item['advance']['advance_salary'] }}
@endif
</td>
<td>
    @php
        $amount = $item->salary - $item['advance']['advance_salary'];
    @endphp
    <strong style="color: #fff;"> {{ round($amount) }} </strong>
 </td>
```

Trying to access array offset on value of type null already Run these commands

```
composer update 

php artisan cache:clear <br>
php artisan config:clear<br>
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: Not sure why you think any of those commands would be relevant? Have you googled the error message? You didn't say which line causes the error, but you're trying to access an array element of a variable which is actually null, so obviously there's no item to access. Probably either `$item['advance']` or `$data` itself is null. Have you done any debugging to try and work out which one it is, or trace back in your code to discover why it doesn't contain the the value your code is expecting it to?

Comment: id employee_id month year advance_salary 
1         4                   December 2022    20000
2         3                  December  2022    25000
3         1                  December  2022    1000

Comment: Not sure what that is supposed to be, or why it's relevant. But if you have an update, please [edit] your question then you can provide the information in context, and properly formatted, and with sufficient detail. Thanks

Comment: Re your edit... 1) read Piotr's answer below, and 2) as I mentioned in my first comment, do some basic debugging

Answer (score 2):

In some places you expect `$item` to be an object (`$item->salary`), in other you treat `$item` as an array (`$item['advance']['advance_salary']`).
Fix them first and in the process probably you'll fix the error.